# Unit test NullReferenceException with string property problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm writing unit test for ASP.MVC 3 app with EF 4.0 and I have problem with System.NullReferenceException during the testing. I'm  testing this method in service layer:

```
public IQueryable<Pricing> GetPricing(int categoryID)
    {
        var query = from t in _repository.GetAllPricing()
                    where t.FK_Category == categoryID
                    where t.Status.Equals("1")
                    select t;
        return query;
    }
```

It's working fine. But when Status equals to null and I call

```
svc.GetPricing(1).Count();
```

in the test method, then it throws exception. I'm using fake repository and other (empty) string works well.

I've tried to use `pricing.Status = Convert.ToString(null);` instead of `pricing.Status = null;` but this doesn work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't call `.Equals` on a null reference - it will as you've experienced throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Instead you can call the equality operator:

```
public IQueryable<Pricing> GetPricing(int categoryID)
{
    var query = from t in _repository.GetAllPricing()
                where t.FK_Category == categoryID
                where t.Status == "1"
                select t;
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, test pass now. So when use Equals and when ==? Application worked fine with Equals to, only tests fail.

Comment: variable.Equals(other) will work UNLESS variable is (or could be) null. I'd stick to == to be on the safe side.